# animate left not working on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two div's in pink and sky blue color, I make them the same height and width. Pink div is almost covering the height of my screen, when I scroll down and  scrollbar reaches the sky blue then I want to animate blue div to right and when that scrollbar leave that div I want that div to move back where it comes from.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scrollTop(function(){

$(this).scroll(function(){

var scrollTopOrBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();

  if(flag === 0 && scrollTopOrBottom < 1256){
    $('#blueDiv').animate({right: '200px'}, function(){
        flag = 1;
    });
 }

if(flag === 1 && scrollTopOrBottom < 740){
    console.log(scrollTopOrBottom);
 $('#blueDiv').slideLeft();
    flag = 0;
   }    

     });
  });   

});
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mohsinali/770goc04/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply this logic:

1. Use `transition` to animate the element, for that some css like this:

   ```
   #blueDiv {
     width: 50%;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: blue;
     position: absolute;
     left:0;
     transition:left 2s linear;
   }
   #blueDiv.right {
     left:50%
   }
   ```
2. With Jquery check how far is the element sky from the top and trigger the event if the scroll reach that:

   ```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var offT = $('#two').offset().top - $(window).height(),
           scrT = $(window).scrollTop();
       if(scrT >= offT) {
          $('#blueDiv').addClass('right')
       } else {
          $('#blueDiv').removeClass('right')
       }
   });
   ```

---

## [Jquery Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/770goc04/7/)

Comment: It's almost what I am want

Comment: just one more thing, I thing it's not going backward as it's coming forward, how can it go back, I mean slide back

Comment: @mohsinali it's going back after the element isn't visible

Comment: @mohsinali np mate glad to help U