# how to auto detect the scrollTop position of a particular Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to implement the scroll based animation. I mean i want to animate the content of a particular div when it comes in the view. To achieve this i have given the hard coded value to like

```
 if($(window).scrollTop() > 700)
```

if there are so many section on a page then for all of them i will have to give the hard coded values.

is there a way to detect if a particular div is in view?

here is my HTML , CSS and JS.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="container clearFix container1">
    <div class="text1">

    </div>  
    <div class="text2">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="container clearFix">
    <div class="text1">

    </div>  
    <div class="text2">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="container clearFix">
    <div class="text1">

    </div>  
    <div class="text2">

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;

}
.clearFix{
    clear: both;
}
.container > div{
    display: block;
    width: 22%;
    height: 300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color: #ccc; 
    padding: 10px;  
    text-align: justify;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.text1{
    left: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.text2{ 
    right: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
}
.container:nth-child(3) .text1{

    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    left: 200px;
}
.container:nth-child(3) .text2{

    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    right: 200px;   
}
.section2T1{
    transform: translate(200px) rotate(360deg) ;
    opacity: 1;
}
.section2T2{
    transform: translate(-200px) rotate(360deg) ;
    opacity: 1;
}
.section3T1{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
.section3T2{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) !important;
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".container:nth-child(1) .text1").delay(500).animate( {
            left:200,
            opacity: 1
        },500);

    $(".container:nth-child(1) .text2").delay(500).animate( {
        right:200,
        opacity: 1
    },500);

    $(document).on("scroll",function(){ 


        if($(window).scrollTop() > 150){

            $(".container:nth-child(2) .text1").delay(500).addClass("section2T1");

            $(".container:nth-child(2) .text2").delay(500).addClass("section2T2");
        }
        else{
            $(".container:nth-child(2) .text1").delay(500).removeClass("section2T1");

            $(".container:nth-child(2) .text2").delay(500).removeClass("section2T2");

        }


        if($(window).scrollTop() > 700){

            $(".container:nth-child(3) .text1").delay(500).addClass("section3T1");

            $(".container:nth-child(3) .text2").delay(500).addClass("section3T2");
        }
        else{
            $(".container:nth-child(3) .text1").delay(500).removeClass("section3T1");

            $(".container:nth-child(3)        .text2").delay(500).removeClass("section3T2");
        }
   }); 
});
```

Comment: To evaluate if an element is on the view you need a little math between height of window offset of element and scrolltop value ... check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642726/animate-left-not-working-on-page-scroll/39643143#39643143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the position of a div compared to the page, you would use `.offset()`.

```
var divTop = $('div').offset().top;
```

This will give you a variable for the top of the selected container.  You just put that in where you have:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > divTop)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the offset method:

```
$("#myDiv").offset().top
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position of an element using jQuery:

```
$("YOURSELECTOR").position().top;
```